# How to check if Location service is turned on for application?

Tags: iphone, geolocation, gps

I have application which uses user's location. On start of app loading it asks user for location. How can I check after that if user is accepted to share location in my application?

Comment: read the docu of LocationAwareness guide, this is all perfectly explained there.

Comment: You could post that comment like you on every Stack question :)

Comment: on every question that should be closed ;-) (But I also stated the correct document!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [CLLocationManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CLLocationManager/locationServicesEnabled) Reference

> Returns a Boolean value indicating whether location services are
>   enabled on the device.
>
> - (BOOL)locationServicesEnabled Return Value YES if location services are enabled; NO if they are not.
>
> Discussion The user can enable or disable location services from the
>   Settings application by toggling the Location Services switch in
>   General.
>
> You should check the return value of this method before starting
>   location updates to determine whether the user has location services
>   enabled for the current device. If this method returns NO and you
>   start location updates anyway, the Core Location framework prompts the
>   user to confirm whether location services should be reenabled

So if your app has parts that runs without locations, then dont start location updates at app start. once the user chooses a feature that needs location updates 
read the value of `[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]`.
 if false post an alert, like Apple maps when you press the arrow (Locate me) button.
 if true start location updates.